# How to make by bot to leave a server with a guild id

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to leave a discord server by using `;leave <GuildID>`.

The code below does not work:

```js
if (message.guild.id.size < 1)
  return message.reply("You must supply a Guild ID");
if (!message.author.id == 740603220279164939)
  return;

message.guild.leave()
  .then(g => console.log(`I left ${g}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Although it won't fix your problem, I just wanted to mention that `!message.author.id == 740603220279164939` will always return `false` as you convert `message.author.id` to a boolean using the `!` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not supposed to be looking at `message.guild.id`, since that returns the ID of the guild you're sending the message in. If you want to get the guild ID from `;leave (guild id)`, you'll have to cut out the second part using something like `.split()`.

```js
// When split, the result is [";leave", "guild-id"]. You can access the
// guild ID with [1] (the second item in the array).
var targetGuild = message.content.split(" ")[1];
```

`!message.author.id` will convert the author ID (in this case, your bot ID) into a boolean, which results to `false` (since the ID is set and is not a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value). I'm assuming that you mean to have this run only if it the author is not the bot itself, and in that case, you're most likely aiming for this:

```js
// You're supposed to use strings for snowflakes. Don't use numbers.
if (message.author.id == "740603220279164939") return;
```

And now, you just have to use the guild ID that you got from the message content and use that to leave the guild. To do that, just grab the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) from your [bot cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds), and then call `.leave()`. All in all, your code should now look like this:

```js
// Get the guild ID
var targetGuild = message.content.split(" ")[1];
if (!targetGuild) // targetGuild is undefined if an ID was not supplied
    return message.reply("You must supply a Guild ID");

if (message.author.id == "740603220279164939") // Don't listen to self.
    return;

client.guilds.cache.get(targetGuild) // Grab the guild
    .leave() // Leave
    .then(g => console.log(`I left ${g}`)) // Give confirmation after leaving
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Great, but when i type ;leave <guild-id> my bot doesnt do anything.. No errors in console either.. I copied guild id i tried it in, sent ;leave (id) And my bot didn't leave..

Comment: @Axmyo Sure that your command checks work properly? I'm definitely certain that the above works. Try checking to see if you're properly routing your commands.

Comment: it doesnt really work, I don't know why.. When I supply guild id it doesnt do anything (https://imgur.com/a/hsFPFSL), and bot stays in guild that "mentioned" in ;leave (https://imgur.com/a/5x8uoOF)

Comment: @Axmyo I accidentally made a wrong assumption about your code since the original question lacked context. I've edited my solution now. Try the edited version now and feel free to tell me if it still doesn't work.